# weak left arm - forced to drop sets inbetween

Tags: pain

I have a weak left hand compared to right hand, how can I deal with this problem when lifting dumb bells and bench presses. Often it gets really bad and my left arm just gives away. How can I strengthen my left arm more.

I dont want to drop the bells in between sets. Rather I want to do it properly and in correct form.

Please do advise.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably lifting too heavy for your left arm. Switch to dumbbells to ensure that your right arm can't compensate and drop the weights until you can complete your sets using proper form with your left arm. If you want to give your left arm an extra boost, perform additional sets **with your left only** using the right to assist. Working out your right arm independently will only increase the imbalance.

While your right arm won't 'grow' during this time, it will allow your left arm time catch-up.

If you are concerned, speak with a medical professional to see if there are additional causes for the imbalance.

Comment: I'd like to expand: saying "You are lifting too heavy for your left arm" is just one way of saying "You are lifting too heavy". A weight at which you can perform the exercise with proper form is a weight at which you should be training. Drop back to that kind of weight, and follow a strength training progression from that point.

Comment: @Lego, I am suffering from same issue. I am lefty and my right arm is weaker. My trainer forces me to complete the sets and increases the weight in every set. I have just started, nearly 2 months now. I feel my right forarm will blast if I continue in some sets whereas left arm does not pain that much. What should I do? Should I use dumbbells for right arm at home during off days? I go to gym 3 days a week.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are very new to lifting weights and your dominant arm is much stronger. It will always be the case, to varying degrees, that one limb is stronger than the other. So it is not something to be really worried about.

I remember distinctly that my left arm was noticeably weaker in the bench press and overhead press when I was just starting. However this evened out with time, and I didn't do anything specific to address the issue.

If you are not a novice and this is a sudden occurrence, it is time to worry and you should see a physician.